# Why does the output of free -h use different digit separators when run by cron?

Tags: cron, locale

Why does the human readable format of the memory tool `free` print its numbers using full stops when I print it, but when its run by crontab it uses commas?

Sample:

`free -h`

```
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3.7G       2.3G       1.4G       145M       675M       869M
-/+ buffers/cache:       839M       2.9G
Swap:         3.9G       385M       3.5G
```

But when run by crontab:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3,7G       2,3G       1,4G       145M       675M       869M
-/+ buffers/cache:       840M       2,9G
Swap:         3,9G       385M       3,5G
```

I would call this a bug as its a very unexpected behaviour. It's a formula for mistakes.

Comment: What awful distro had crond setup to run cron jobs with a bogus-behavior `LC_NUMERIC`? Yes that's a formula for mistakes, or rather for disaster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your locale settings are different in your shell and in your cronjob. You can check by running `locale` in both settings, and you can change your cronjob's locale settings by setting the appropriate variables (`LC_ALL` is the hammer if you don't need to be subtle; see [`locale(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) for details).

Comment: http://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/02/locale-settings-for-your-cron-job/

Answer (score 1):

The answers that involve setting the *locale* are correct. But there's another solution: don't use the `-h` flag.

When you specify `free -h` (or, equivalently, `free --human`), you are asking for a human-readable output format, which is not necessarily easy to parse by a computer. If you use the default output format, it will be parseable and locale-independent.